# uploading file to firebase storage using angularfire

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 for uploading image to the firebase storage. The upload works just fine though i have trouble in the timing to wait for my code for the download url to be available.  Here is the code when file gets picked

```
 async onFilesAdded(event){
      console.log("file added")
      if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log("File name is:" + file.name)

         await this.dataSvc.pushUpload(file).then(
            (res) => {
              console.log("download url is::" + this.dataSvc.downloadURL)
            },
            (err) => console.log("fail to upload file:" + err)
          )


      }
    }
```

My service implements it as below

```
 pushUpload(file: File) {
    const filePath = '/' + file.name;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
         const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

          task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
   ).subscribe(
        res => resolve(res),
        err => reject(err))
   }
   )
  }
```

I am hoping to wait until the promise is resolved and i see the download url. But my code does not seems to wait and i get the downloadUrl undefined and after few sec the download url actually shows up in service. So basically my code calling the pushUpload is not waiting for the download to finish.

Another variation where i never get the download url inside finalize

```
pushUpload(file: File) {
    const path = '/' + file.name;
    const ref = this.storage.ref(path);

    let task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
    let snapshot   = task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize( async() =>  {
        this.downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
        console.log("download url i got is:" + this.downloadURL)
      }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download seems to finish correctly. But you resolve your promise with the first emitted value from the `snapshotChanges` observable, which does not have the property `downloadURL` hence the undefined result.

You should subscribe to the `fileRef.getDownloadURL()` observable to get your URL.

```
pushUpload(file: File) {
    const filePath = '/' + file.name;
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

        task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            finalize(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(
                res => resolve(res),
                err => reject(err));
            )
        ).subscribe();
    })
}
```

The code looks a little bit ugly with the promise approach. I do not know if you could subscribe inside a subscription, i never did this before.

As soon as the `snapshotChanges` observable completes the `finalize` operation triggers and subscribes to the `fileRef.getDownloadURL()` observable, this observable should emit the URL immediately and resolves the promise.

And i would recommend to use the observable instead of creating a new promise.

Comment: how would you define and iniitalize downLoadUrl in this case? i initialized it as  downloadURL:Observable<string> but then hit issue that it is undefined when i subscribe to it

Comment: Sorry, i have misread the RxJs documentation. The finalize function does not get called until the snapshotChanges observable completes. I have edited the code but i do not know if the subscription inside a subscription works. I could give you an example without promise, if this approach does not work.

Comment: yes without promise will do well. all i need is to get the download url in my calling code

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get the URL other than the answer above is:

```
const file = event.target.files[0];
const filePath = `myfolder/${file.name}`;
const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    filter((snapshot) => snapshot.state === 'success'),
    switchMap(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL())
 )
.subscribe({
    next: (url) => {console.log(url)},
    error: (err) => {console.error(err.message)}
})
```

The observable of the uploader snapshot will filter all of its emissions until the state is set as success, so it's possible to call the getDownloadURL method once the download is finished through switchMap, which will return the result within a single subscription.